# Change node names in XML

Tags: r, xml

I have two types of `XML`: `myxml` and `myxml2` that turn them into `DF`. The nodes of these two `XML` are different, one starts with `test` and the other starts with `test2`. See below:

```
##myxml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>


<test:TASS xmlns="http://www.vvv.com/schemas"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vvv.com/schemas http://www.vvv.com/schemas/testV2_02_03.xsd"  xmlns:test="http://www.vvv.com/schemas" >
                <test:billing>
                    <test:proceduresummary>
                        <test:guidenumber>X2030</test:guidenumber>
                            <test:diagnosis>
                                <test:table>ICD-10</test:table>
                                <test:diagnosiscod>J441</test:diagnosiscod>
                                <test:description>CHRONIC OBSTRUCTIVE PULMONARY DISEASE WITH (ACUTE) EXACERBATION</test:description>
                            </test:diagnosis>
                            <test:procedure>
                                <test:procedure>
                                    <test:description>HOSPITAL</test:description>
                                </test:procedure>
                                <test:amount>12</test:amount>
                            </test:procedure>
                    </test:proceduresummary>
                    </test:billing>
</test:TASS>
```

Code to turn into DF (xml=test)

```
#require(tidyverse)
#require(xml2)
#setwd("D:/")
#myxml<- read_xml("test.xml")
#myxml<-myxml %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing")
#billing1<-xml2::as_list(myxml) %>% jsonlite::toJSON() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

Now my XML = test2

```
##myxml2

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>


<test2:TASS xmlns="http://www.vvv.com/schemas"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vvv.com/schemas http://www.vvv.com/schemas/testV2_02_03.xsd"  xmlns:test2="http://www.vvv.com/schemas" >
                <test2:billing>
                    <test2:proceduresummary>
                        <test2:guidenumber>Z4088</test2:guidenumber>
                            <test2:diagnosis>
                                <test2:table>ICD-10</test2:table>
                                <test2:diagnosiscod>G93</test2:diagnosiscod>
                                <test2:description>DISORDER OF BRAIN, UNSPECIFIED</test2:description>
                            </test2:diagnosis>
                            <test2:procedure>
                                <test2:procedure>
                                    <test2:description>HOSPITAL</test2:description>
                                </test2:procedure>
                                <test2:amount>15</test2:amount>
                            </test2:procedure>
                    </test2:proceduresummary>
                </test2:billing>
</test2:TASS>
```

Code to turn into DF (xml=test2)

```
#setwd("D:/")
#myxml2<- read_xml("test2.xml")
#myxml2<-myxml2 %>% xml_find_all(".//test2:billing")
#billing2<-xml2::as_list(myxml2) %>% jsonlite::toJSON() %>% jsonlite::fromJSON()
```

I need to create code that changes these nodes names. I thought of using a function before "xml_find_all" to swap all nodes, for example, so importing all nodes would be called "bd" instead of "test" or "test2". It is possible?

Comment: From XML point of view, both the `test` and `test2` namespaces are equivalent, as they both represent the same URI `http://www.vvv.com/schemas`.

Comment: @choroba however, when I do xml_find_all (".// test2: billing") I have to determine the path (test or test2). Without that I get into an error and I can't go on

Comment: I don't know R, but in other languages, you first *register* the namespace, and you can then refer to the nodes regardless of what prefix the namespace uses in the document. I would be quite surprised if R was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second file is the same as the first file with the exception that "test:" was converted to "test2:".  One option is to store all of the xPath searches as vector and then using the `sub` function make the substitution.

In this file the namespaces are define a more direct approach is just to rename the namespace and reuse the code as shown below. This method works for this file, I can't say this is completely general approach.

```
library(xml2)

page<-read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<test2:TASS xmlns="http://www.vvv.com/schemas"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.vvv.com/schemas http://www.vvv.com/schemas/testV2_02_03.xsd"  
xmlns:test2="http://www.vvv.com/schemas" >
                <test2:billing>
                    <test2:proceduresummary>
                        <test2:guidenumber>Z4088</test2:guidenumber>
                            <test2:diagnosis>
                                <test2:table>ICD-10</test2:table>
                                <test2:diagnosiscod>G93</test2:diagnosiscod>
                                <test2:description>DISORDER OF BRAIN, UNSPECIFIED</test2:description>
                            </test2:diagnosis>
                            <test2:procedure>
                                <test2:procedure>
                                    <test2:description>HOSPITAL</test2:description>
                                </test2:procedure>
                                <test2:amount>15</test2:amount>
                            </test2:procedure>
                    </test2:proceduresummary>
                </test2:billing>
</test2:TASS>')
#xml_ns_strip(page)

#display the name spaces
xml_ns(page)
# d1    <-> http://www.vvv.com/schemas
# test2 <-> http://www.vvv.com/schemas
# xsi   <-> http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

#rename test2 to become test to reuse existing code
ns<-xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(page), test2 = "test")
t2<-page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing", ns) #also works

#demonstration purposes (not needed in production code)
    t1<-page %>% xml_find_all(".//test2:billing")  # works
    t3<-page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing")   # fails

    identical(t1, t2)
#[1] TRUE
#end of demo
```

**Edit:**
As per your comments if you don't know whether the XML has test or test2 as the namespace then you can use the following test to determine whether or not you need to rename the namespace.

```
if ("test2" %in%  names(xml_ns(page))) {
  #print(TRUE)
  ns<-xml_ns_rename(xml_ns(page), test2 = "test")
} else {
  #print(FALSE)
  ns<- xml_ns(page)
}

#this should now work for both cases.
page %>% xml_find_all(".//test:billing", ns)
```

Comment: Your answer was good, but I need the change to occur before this part "t1 <-page%>% xml_find_all (" .// test2: billing ")". It is possible?

Comment: I sorry, I am not understanding the question.  Do you need the xml text changed or just the query parts changed?    The `xml_ns_rename` line is the key line added.  I edited the script above to clarify the demo part.

Comment: Perfect, it worked!. In my work I will deal with both of these namespace types (test and test2). I will try to automate code that identifies when to change from "test2" to "test" and when not to change (test to test). I thought I used if_else, but it didn't work. I will keep trying, if you know of any suggestions would be welcome! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately my XML files don't have much of a standard. I have another problem, and as you have a lot of knowledge I would like you to check my problem at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208452/how-to-transform-list-to-data-frame-in-xml-file